# Trouble installing elasticsearch

Tags: elasticsearch

while doing $sudo dpkg -i elasticsearch-0.90.10.deb

it gives the following error :

Processing triggers for man-db ...
Setting up elasticsearch (0.90.10) ...
chown: cannot access `/etc/elasticsearch/*': No such file or directory
dpkg: error processing elasticsearch (--install):
 subprocess installed post-installation script returned error exit status 1
Processing triggers for ureadahead ...
Errors were encountered while processing:
 elasticsearch

directory /etc/elasticsearch exists and I am not able to gather proper reason for it.

Comment: have you considered just unpacking a zip/gz download and using it, instead of the deb?

Comment: Had the same issue on ubuntu 14.04 with packages provided by elastic. AnthonyT's answer solved it.

Answer (score 2):

I didn't have any files in /etc/elasticsearch didn't have any files in it and thus caused an error.  Just put a file in the directory and it will do the update or install file;

```
sudo touch /etc/elasticsearch/tmp
```

Comment: This seems counter intuitive, but it worked for me. The deb package creates this directory, hence it is empty, but wants to do this:
```sh
chown -Rh root:root /etc/elasticsearch/*
```
Which fails. Adding a dummy file inside solves the issue.

Answer (score 0):

the call in the installation script, which seems to fail, is actually

`chown -Rh root:root /etc/elasticsearch/*`

which is extremely strange. The only thing I can imagine right now, is that you were not having proper privileges (can you show the permissions of `/etc/elasticsearch` - do you have any subdirectories inside it? If so, are those allowed to be accessed (is the executable flag set)? The output of `find /etc/elasticsearch -ls` might be interesting

Does this also happen with newer versions of the debian package (0.90.11 or 1.0.0)?
Also, which distribution are you using?